# D3.Js Link Tree Connections Not Showing [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, graph, d3-force-directed

I'm having issues where my D3 Force Graph is showing with nodes but not connecting the links.
I'm not sure what the issue is because my strokes are defined.

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the JSON Data format or what it could be. Where could the issue be?

I am using Angular D3 with D3.Js & what I am trying to build is a Force Directed Network Graph.

JSON Data I'm using:

```
https://gist.github.com/KoryJCampbell/f18f8a11030269739eabc7de05b38b11
```

**graph.ts**

```
  loadForceDirectedGraph(nodes: Node[], links: Link[]) {
    const svg = d3.select('svg');
    const width = +svg.attr('width');
    const height = +svg.attr('height');

    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeTableau10);


    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d: Node) => d.name))// the id of the node
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5).distanceMax(0.1 * Math.min(width, height)))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    console.log(nodes, links);

    const link = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'links')
      .selectAll('line')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', d => Math.sqrt(d.index))
      .attr('stroke', 'black');



    const node = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'nodes')
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.company); })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragStarted)
        .on('drag', dragged)
        .on('end', dragEnded)
      );


    node.append('title').text((d) => d.name);

    simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on('tick', ticked);

    simulation.force<d3.ForceLink<any, any>>('link')
      .links(links);

    function ticked() {
      node
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);

      link
          .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
          .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
          .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
          .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);
    }

    function dragStarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) { simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart(); }
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.y;
    }

    function dragEnded(event) {
      if (!event.active) { simulation.alphaTarget(0); }
      event.subject.fx = null;
      event.subject.fy = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the json data from the url as is?

Comment: Well the json is stored in a local file on my computer but the format & object is the exact same @NiK648

Comment: can you provide a snippet or sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your links format in json file is wrong.

change links to this format.

```js
links: [
    {
      source: "<paste source's name property>",
      target: "<paste target's name property>",
      index: 0
    },
  ]
```

because you are doing:

```js
 .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d: Node) => d.name))// the name of the node
```